# 401 errors after switching Capybara default driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm putting together [feature specs](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications) for an existing Rails app using Capybara and RSpec.  By default, Capybara uses `rack_test` as the driver, but I want to use capybara-webkit.

I've put together a simple test to log in to my site. Using `rack_test` I'm able to log in, and my `log/test.log` file shows the following HTTP requests:

```
Completed 200 OK in 201ms (Views: 201.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-01 10:20:33 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"foo@bar.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'foo@bar.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   # There are a few more SQL queries here that I've removed
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-01 10:20:33 -0600
Processing by InitiativesController#blank as HTML
```

I'm having issues with running this test when I switch to webkit (by setting `Capybara.default_driver :webkit` in `spec_helper.rb`).  For some reason I am seeing 401 errors in the log:

```
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 16.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-01 10:21:31 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"foo@bar.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'foo@bar.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  # no other queries
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
```

So the log in request is not being accepted.  Is there some sort of Capybara configuration that I need to change in order to get this log in request to work?  I can't figure out what is causing this.

My `spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'fakeredis/rspec'
require 'site_prism'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
Capybara.default_host = 'http://127.0.0.1:60400'
Capybara.server_port = 60400

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_unknown_urls
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => [:controller, :acceptance]

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation 
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:all) do
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

  config.before :each do
    Timecop.return
  end

  config.include Helpers
  config.include Helpers::MassAdsCreation
end

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Comment: can you share your spec_helper? In general, I'd say that you have to download the `qt` libraries and install the gem, then add `gem 'capybara-webkit'`to your gemfile, add `require 'capybara-webkit'`, `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` and `config.include Capybara::DSL` to your `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: Just added my `spec_helper.rb` to the question

Comment: can you try do remove `config.block_unknown_urls`?

Comment: did you find a way to fix it? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @zywx This ended up being a Devise issue.  It's been so long since I looked at this that I don't remember the exact fix, but I think it involved using the `Warden::Test::Helpers` mentioned in one of the answers below along with some bugs specific to my app.

Comment: Yes we investigate that way but we still didn't succeed. It must be relative to our app since a new fresh rails app out of the box don't have this kind of problem... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use the `Warden::Test::Helpers` instead [as described here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

Note that they have  a specific section dealing with `capybara-webkit` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 probably means the password doesn't match the email you're using to login.  Since its working for you with rack_test but not capybara-webkit it's most likely you are still using transaction based testing.
When using rack_test the application is run in the same thread as the tests which means they are both using the same database connection.  Because of that you can used transaction based testing and never have to pay the performance penalty of actually writing anything to the database.  However when using any "real browser" driver Capybara starts your app in it's own thread which means the tests and the app are using separate database connections and you therefore have to actually commit to the database.  This is generally done by using database_cleaner in truncation mode.  See https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Comment: I just tried this.  Adding database truncation did not fix the 401 errors.

Comment: How are you creating the records?  Did you change to config.use_transactional_fixtures = false  ?  Please post your spec_helper and rails_helper

Comment: I just added my `spec_helper.rb` to the original question.